# Make a network call from code behind's constructor Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am making a network call inside code behind constructor. I have to do this because I am passing parameter to constructor, then using those initiate the network call. Because of I am doing this inside the constructor I have to use Task.Run option which is not a good solution. I tried factory method also but I am unable to use it since passing parameters are done by click event. Can anyone suggest me a better solution. Thanks

```
    Class Home{
    
            private async void HomeLandingListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
                var item = (HomeLanding)e.Item;
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new PolicyDetailsMotor(item.id, p_end_date));
            }
    
    }
```

Network call class

```
public partial class PolicyDetailsMotor : ContentPage
    {

        public PolicyDetailsMotor(string id, string p_end_date)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.id = id;
            this.p_end_date = p_end_date;

            Title = "Motor Policy Details";

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                var result = await api_class.getMotorPolicyDetails(id, p_end_date);               

            });

        }

}
```

Comment: put the call in OnAppearing

Comment: use event to command behaviour and use the on appearing in Viewmodel also use messenger instance of xamarin to send these variable.

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Jason one problem in onappearing is when I goto next page and come back, data load again

Comment: Set a bool when data is loaded and only make the request if it is false